# Multipole Expansion of the Electromagnetic Field of A Rotating Particle

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, multipole-expansion

> In the case of a particle $q$ orbiting in a circle with $\omega_0$ and $r_0$, the current density $\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t)$ contains frequency at $\omega_0$ (dipole) and $2\omega_0$ (quadrupole), $3\omega_0$ ...

How to prove this? I know the dipole is $qr_0(\hat{x}+i\hat{y})\mathrm{e}^{i\omega_0 t}$ but I don't know how to write the current density/quadrupole of the particle. It seems that this can be proved by Fourier series. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try writing the equations for the charge and current density of a [point particle](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Book%3A_Applications_of_Maxwells_Equations_(Cochran_and_Heinrich)/07%3A_Time_Dependent_Electromagnetic_Fields./7.06%3A_A_Moving_Point_Charge_in_Vacuum) and then use [integral expressions for multipoles](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Physics_and_Pedagogy/Mathematical_Methods/The_Multipole_Expansion). You will get time-dependent multipole expressions, and then you can use Fourier trasnform etc

Comment: Hint. For a moving point-charge $q$, the charge density is $\rho\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)=q\delta\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}\left(t\right)\right)$, where $\mathbf{R}\left(t\right)$ is the charge position at time $t$. Electric dipole is $\mathbf{p}=\int d^3r \mathbf{r}\rho$